# Show and hide JPane and Layout

Tags: java

I am new for Java. I need to create the desktop app that the JPane can hide and show. It just like hide and show the div in HTML.  Is it JPane? What is the layout I need to use?

[image]

Comment: search for docking or accordion

Comment: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=236

Comment: @peeskillet, thanks it is a good article.  How can I click your as answer?

Comment: @user819774 no need. I don't really like posting link only answers. Glad it worked out for you though :-)